# How to show display a person's age automatically in textbox whenever a person's name in selected in list view?

Tags: vb.net

My program has a textbox and a listview. In the list view i have added three person's name, John, Kat, Adel.

How do I make it such that when John's name is selected in list view, John's age is automatically displayed in the text box?

And when Kat's name is selected in list view, Kat's age is automatically displayed in the text box?

Same goes to Adel as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you should write the code in the **SelectedIndexChanged** event of the listbox

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

      ' John, Kat, Adel 
    SELECT CASE ListBox1.Text.Tolower.Trim
        CASE "john"
             TextBox1.Text = "15" ' - the age you want to display
        CASE "kat"
             TextBox1.Text = "16"
        CASE "adel"
             TextBox1.Text = "17"
    END SELECT

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

      ' John, Kat, Adel 

    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi johntotetwoo. Thanks so much for the brilliant help! Really appreciate it! I was wondering if it is possible to return an index from the listbox1 when either john or kat or adel is selected and based on the index return the age. i am a total newbie to this in coding and your help will be appreciated!

Comment: While this is a working example - you may want to look into using a custom class object. You could create a class that has a Name and Age property, and bind the ListBox to that. Then you could access the age directly with something like `ListBox1.SelectedItem.Age`. This would also be much easier to manage, instead of creating a case for each person you want to add.

Comment: I see thank a lot. I will try to look into creating a custom class object. Actually I was trying to write a windows mobile 6.5 application for my school project. Hmm... so ListBox1.Text.ToLower.Trim didn't work.
I tried select case listbox1.focuseditem.text.tolower.trim instead. However i got an error when the first
item was selected. The error was "NullReferenceException was unhandled". I don't know how to solve this error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should look at the member functions / properties of any objects you're unsure about. Like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the ListBox, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for strings. The reason I say this is that your `String.ToLower.Trim` is not correct. For the question you have shown - I think that @johntotetwoo has more than answered it. If you are still having problems you should probably do some more research. For vb.net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388568

Answer (score 1):

I normally don't do this - so please don't abuse the help. I still think you should spend more time reading the information at MSDN.com. This link is a great resource for people new to VB.Net development: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388568

I wrote this against the 3.0 framework, which is as close as I can get to developing for Windows Mobile 6.5 in Visual Studio 2010. Some of these functions may not work in your application, but it should convey the basic idea.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Here we create a new generic list of our User class with some preloaded items.
        Dim users As New List(Of User) From {New User("John", 15), New User("Kat", 16), New User("Adel", 17)}

        ' Here we will add another user at after the list has already been created.
        users.Add(New User("Bob", "18"))

        ' Set the DataSource of the listbox to our users
        Me.ListBox1.DataSource = users

        ' Set the DisplayMember to the Name property of the User so the list will show the names of the users.
        Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"

    End Sub

    ' This event is fired when a different item in the listbox is selected
    ' This event will fire when the ListBox is bound to a datasource.
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ' If there is an item selected (i.e. the index is not -1)
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            '   Create a temporary variable to store the currently selected item (which is a user)
            '   We could have used CType instead to avoid this variable
            Dim selectedUser As User = ListBox1.SelectedItem

            ' Set the textbox text to the User class's age.
            TextBox1.Text = selectedUser.Age
        Else
            ' If we are here then it means no item is selected in the listbox.
            ' Empty the textbox.
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

' Create a User class with a Name and Age propery.
Class User
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer

    ' Create a constructor that accepts a Name (string) and an Age (integer)
    Public Sub New(ByVal _name As String, ByVal _age As Integer)
        Me.Name = _name
        Me.Age = _age
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback function on change of listview value, in this function check which value has been selected i.e John, Kat or Adel and then set appropiate age in textbox.